# Is there a way I could display a token (for exmaple user ID) as a default field content to a content type?

Tags: entities, tokens

Is there a way I could display a token (for exmaple user ID) as a default field content to a content type?

Id like to display a node form to users
/node/add/content type

when a user goes to that page the field "name" automatically displays the user id.

name: [user:uid] - something like that

Is it possible, If so, how can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it to be editable or not?

Either way, its going to take a small custom module with [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) or [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) if you want to target a specific form.

If you want it editable:

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#default_value

If you want it set at a value:

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#value

Start with downloading and enabling devel and a small module with just this to get a list of all the form elements on a page:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_NAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  dsm($form_id);  // print form ID to messages
  dsm($form);  // pretty print array using Krumo to messages
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't a module for that.

Check these links though; people posted some patches but I haven't tried any of them.

http://drupal.org/node/1070878

http://drupal.org/node/700230

http://drupal.org/node/700230

http://drupal.org/node/1308564

On the other hand, I think you can use hook_form_alter() to set the default field value on that node add form.